# I need fly/flying power

Tags: verb-forms, word-form

You want to fly and need magic power for that.

Which sentence would be approriate?

1. I need flying power.
2. I need fly power.

Comment: You need the power to fly.

Comment: Thank you. What if you are refering to the type of power, which power would be?

Comment: I beg your pardon, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Is this in relation to a game? If it is then it's probably "I need flying power" but be aware that while it is common usage in gaming it's not something that would normally be used in written or conversational English

Comment: @StoneyB I think I got what OP meant, but I don't have the answer :-( I need your help. Say if a man has a power of invisibility, the man can become invisible whenever he wishes. So OP is asking what is the name of the power that enables one to fly. Is it "the power of flying"? Please help here.

Comment: These should work: *I need the/more (magic) power for flying.* *I need the/more (magic) power to fly.* *I need the/more (magic) power of flight.* If Fly/Flying/Flight Power is a proper name in your game, then these should work too: *I need Fly/Flying/Flight Power* or if it's a spell: *I need the spell of Fly/Flying/Flight Power*.

Comment: Thank you everyone. This isn't related to a game but Man from india got what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you everyone. This isn't related to a game, and Man from india got what I was looking for, but @PerryW and Damkerng, how could this language work for gaming but not for regular conversation? So, with your game in front, you woukd understand intantly, but as soon as you leave the screen, you would scrach your head for the meaning?

Comment: @Joe Kim Like many special interest groups, specialities and sub-cultures, games have developed domain specific usages - you have 'power-ups' that grant bonuses when the player achieves a goal, these may be increases in existing attributes or new powers - this is where you will hear terms like "you have earned the flying power".  I don’t think I've heard this compound noun form used outside of games - as has been pointed out already, in normal conversation you would most likely 'get the power of flight' or 'the power to fly'

Answer (score 1):

Neither works.

> I need the power to fly.

Although, a better sentence would be

> I need the power of flight.